# Que signifie "cuiller" dans ce cas ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, littérature

Que signifie **cuiller** dans ce cas ? Céline écrit dans *Guignol's Band* :

"Plutôt arriver marée basse, comme ça ni vu, ni connu, ou la nuit en embarcation, alors marée haute, et molo **à la cuiller**!..." (CÉLINE, 1951, p. 39).

J’imagine qu’il s’agit d’utiliser doucement la rame qui permet de naviguer sans se faire remarquer. Le problème c’est que je ne trouve nulle part cuiller = rame…

Answer (score 2):

À mon avis il ne s'agit pas de la rame mais de la main. Céline aime jouer avec les expressions et il a détourné l'expression argotique « serrer la cuillère »<sup>1</sup> dans laquelle cuillère désigne la main.

Cet emploi métaphorique du mot cuillère pour désigner la main ne se trouve (en dehors de la création célinienne) que dans l'expression « serrer la cuillère » ; cet emploi est né au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle à cause de l'analogie de forme entre l'instrument et la main, paume creusée au bout du bras. Avant le 19<sup>e</sup> siècle le mot louche était déjà employé pour désigner la main en argot (*serrer la louche*, *mettre la louche au panier*,...).

En disant « molo à la cuiller » le tenancier leur recommande d'y aller doucement, de ne pas trop agiter leurs mains.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Donner une poignée de main.</sup>

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse. À votre avis, porquoi il écrit "molo" et non "mollo" ? Est-ce juste pour la jubilation de la langue ? Il y a des exemples inombrables des variations ortographiques dans ce roman, presque sur chaque page.

Comment: @AFM D'après le contexte je comprends bien que Céline veut dire « mollo » mais je n'ai aucune idée de la raison qui lui fait mettre un seul  *l*, est-ce volontaire ou non ? Lui seul aurait pu le dire !

Comment: Je suppose que c'est une raison esthétique, donc ouverte à l'interprétation de tous et non seulement limité aux intentions de l'auteur. Mais dans le cas des modifications orthographiques, je ne comprends pas du tout quel est le vrai gain artistique.

Comment: Marrant... je n'avais jamais vraiment entendu "serrer la cuillère" avant cette réponse, et voilà qu'hier au hasard d'une rediffusion, j'entends cette expression dans un épisode de "New-York Unité Spéciale" ...